# How to reshape a specific dataset from long to wide without a J variable in Stata?

Tags: stata, stata-macros, readstata13

My dataset looks like the following:

| identification number | year | indicator | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1112000 | 2000 | JKL_ADS | 511 |
| 1112001 | 2001 | JKL_ADS | 517 |
| 1112002 | 2002 | JKL_ADS | 721 |
| 1112003 | 2003 | JKL_ADS | 925 |
| 1112004 | 2004 | JKL_ADS | 1092 |
| 1112000 | 2000 | KLS_DSAK | 351 |
| 1112001 | 2001 | KLS_DSAK | 631 |
| 1112002 | 2002 | KLS_DSAK | 732 |
| 1112003 | 2003 | KLS_DSAK | 823 |
| 1112004 | 2004 | KLS_DSAK | 1092 |

I want to reshape wide so it looks like this instead:

| identification number | year | JKL_ADS | KLS_DSAK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1112000 | 2000 | 511 | 351 |
| 1112001 | 2001 | 517 | 631 |
| 1112002 | 2002 | 721 | 732 |
| 1112003 | 2003 | 925 | 823 |
| 1112004 | 2004 | 1092 | 1092 |

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly standard application. You didn't give example data in recommended form, so the details here may need modification by you.

Contrary to the question, `indicator` serves as an argument to `j()`.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input long identificationnumber int year str8 indicator int data
1112000 2000 "JKL_ADS"   511
1112001 2001 "JKL_ADS"   517
1112002 2002 "JKL_ADS"   721
1112003 2003 "JKL_ADS"   925
1112004 2004 "JKL_ADS"  1092
1112000 2000 "KLS_DSAK"  351
1112001 2001 "KLS_DSAK"  631
1112002 2002 "KLS_DSAK"  732
1112003 2003 "KLS_DSAK"  823
1112004 2004 "KLS_DSAK" 1092
end

. reshape wide data , i(id year) j(indicator) string
(j = JKL_ADS KLS_DSAK)

Data                               Long   ->   Wide
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations               10   ->   5           
Number of variables                   4   ->   4           
j variable (2 values)         indicator   ->   (dropped)
xij variables:
                                   data   ->   dataJKL_ADS dataKLS_DSAK
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename (data*) (*)

. l

     +--------------------------------------+
     | identi~r   year   JKL_ADS   KLS_DSAK |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. |  1112000   2000       511        351 |
  2. |  1112001   2001       517        631 |
  3. |  1112002   2002       721        732 |
  4. |  1112003   2003       925        823 |
  5. |  1112004   2004      1092       1092 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```